# Is potential difference same for all pairs of points such that they are equidistant from opposite terminals in the circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential

Suppose the following circuit has no resistor other than the one drawn. It has a just a resistor, a battery and a wire as shown in figure.

[image]

Is it true that potential difference is same between every two points in figure? If yes, why?

Comment: Every pair of points connected only by a wire (with no element in the middle) is at the same potential, because it is assumed that the wires have $0$ resistance per unit length.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The symbol of the resistor is just a symbol, it has no ulterior meaning.

Comment: OK leave it.  What I understand by reading your first comment is that your answer to my question is yes, somehow. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I wrote it as a comment and  not as an answer because it really isn't a through explanation...

Comment: @valerio92 It's OK with whatever it is but you have now somehow spoiled my previous concepts, I was going with. So now I want an explanation, if you like, that why are the two points with no element between them are supposed to be at same potential. Why the point farther from a terminal than other point is supposed to be at same potential? I think if there is an electric field and I move a charge (say 1C) against it towards positive from negative terminal, it potenial energy changes by the negative of work done by electrostatic force on it and so the charge is now at a higher potential than

Comment: - before even not going through any element. So I think two points or the two positions of the charge are at different potential.     @valerio92

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47215/discussion-between-valerio92-and-sufyan-naeem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ideal wire is no more than an electric device which is caracterised by $U = 0$, with $U$ the potential difference between its two poles. Then, since every two points in your figure are linked by a wire, the potential between every to of them is the same, and is null.

However, you must keep in mind that an *ideal wire* can't exist: any conductor has a resistance, even if it's really low. Then, we can consider  a *real wire* as a resistor whose resistance is negligeable in front of the other resistances of the circuit. Ohm's law then says that $U = RI$, but since $R$ is really small, $U << 1V$: the potential difference between the two ends of a physical wire is almost null.

Comment: Then what about the electric field in the wire due to which the charge flow? In an electric field two points are at different potential and therefore there must be potential difference between any two points in the wire.

Comment: An ideal wire is... ideal. It is only meant to simplify circuit plans, and don't exist. A real wire has a non null resistance, and thus there is a potential difference between its two ends.

Comment: Is it necessary to have some resistance between two points in the field to create potential differece between them?

Comment: No: consider a perfect inductor, we know that $U=L\frac{di}{dt}$,  but it has no resistance. However, having a resistance is sufficient to induce a potential difference.